# Issues with cooking meat and milk at the same time

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, cooking-bishul, appliances, meat-and-milk

What issues are there (either potential or inherent) in cooking meat dishes and milk dishes at the same time on the same stovetop (*not* in the same pot)?

Please also compare benefits and problems between:
* A gas range
* A spiral electric cooktop
* A glass electric cooktop

Comment: @Vram I do not believe electric cooktops of any type have a din of Hamei Teveria, as they are not natural. Acc. to the Gemara (I forget where, sorry), you are not Hayav for Bishul on Shabbath if your food is cooked by the sun, but (I think acc. to Rashi?) this exemption falls apart if the surface becomes hot from the sun and then cooks the food. The Nafka Mina would be a microwave-type of device that operated on a timer or something, which heats the food with rays but doesn't generate surface heat, which would not be Hayav, vs. cooking an egg on your car hood, which would be Hayav...

Comment: @Vram ...None of which has anything to do with my question (at least I don't think so).

Comment: @Vram That's true, but it's not Derech Bishul, whereas any hot survace is considered Derech Bishul. Ergo, spiral electric cooktops (as well as glass electric cooktops) are Derech Bishul.

Comment: @Vram Not having listened to it (yet, though I hope to soon), one more point I'll add is that some say microwaves _are_ Derech Bishul today since they are so common.

Comment: @vram See Yerushalmi Shabbath 7:2. Smoking is Asur on Shabbath. I am learning these Dining tonight, actually. If I'm understanding correctly, this Din of smoking on Shabbath carries over to BB"H, making it Asur, even if RaMBa"M holds one is Patur. But I still don't see how it's relevant.

Comment: @Vram. I did after I posted my comment above. He actually brings my point exactly, and attributes it to the GR"A (which is my source as well). And I apologize for the confusion regarding natural cooking. I should have said Derech Bishul. Cooking via the sun or Hamei Teveriah are Patur bc they aren't Derech Bishul.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[See here where almost the exact same question is asked](http://halachaqa.blogspot.com/2010/12/question-what-do-i-need-to-know-about.html)

Some concerns:

> - Could the taste of milk become transferred from the grate or
>     stove top to a meat pot or vice versa? 
>     In other words when I place my milk pot on the grate right after my meat
>     pot, does the milk pot absorb the taste of meat?
> - May I eat food that falls between the grates or on to the stove top?
> - Steam. Hot visible steam will transfer taste.
> - Dangers of splattering from pot to pot.

See there for more details.

It does not address the differences between the different types of stoves, though I doubt it makes much of a difference.

---

[Another great source](http://halachafortoday.com/ArchivesHilchosKashrus.aspx). (I highly recommend checking out this page. This is only a small excerpt.)

> 1) When using one stovetop for both food classes (which is OK, M'Ikar Hadin as we learned yesterday), the following guidelines must be followed:
>    ·         The entire surface of the stovetop must be treated as a non kosher utensil and no food may be placed directly onto this surface.
>    ·         If any food fell onto this surface while cooking or frying, it becomes prohibited to eat.
>    ·         When cleaning any part of the stovetop it may not be done  together with or on top of any other kosher utensils, and separate cleaning gear are required to clean any part of the stovetop.
>    ·         No utensils (e.g. a stirring spoon) that aren't totally dry on the bottom may be placed on a stovetop that is used for both food classes. (See Rama [Yoreh Deah Siman 92:8](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A6%D7%91#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.97) and Chochmas Adam 45:19. See also Shu"t Sh'eilas Ya'avetz Vol. 1 Siman 113)

As always, CYLOR for questions of practical Halacha.

Answer (score 3):

From a purely practical point of view, an advice from someone who cooks for Shabbat and often tries to keep meat from entering parve dishes, failing in approximately 25% of the cases: don't do it.

Comment: Odd, I've done this many times, and very rarely had a problem.

Comment: @msh210: I envy your ability to concentrate under pressure.

Comment: Malenkiy_scot and @msh210, wouldn't that imply that it's ok? Or do you think you've been doing something wrong? Can you get into issues and complications? (Malenkiy_scot, I think your answer may be better as a comment on the question, since I'm not looking for advice, but for specific issues that apply.)

Comment: @SethJ, you didn't ask whether it's okay: you asked "What issues are there (either potential or inherent)". I know of no issues besides the obvious one that you might drip when carrying food between pots or the like, and the transfer of _taam_ between pots that touch. I didn't think that was a good enough answer to post. Incidentally, I agree: this answer isn't much of one, and would be better as a comment on the question. I won't force the issue, but if you agree, malenkiy_scot, then I can convert it to be a comment on the question.

Comment: I am assuming you define 'ok' as 'halachikally ok'. I do not want to get into halachik  discussions.

Comment: @msh210, I had thought for a minute deciding whether to make it a comment or an answer.